# Use PHP code to create custom user roles. Call it once?

Tags: user-roles

I have the following PHP code in my wordpress site. I have noticed that when I disable the following code, those two user roles still exists both for current and new users.

```
/* ------------------------------ ADD NEW CUSTOM ROLES ------------------------------ */
add_role('barber',_('Barber'),array('read' => true, 'edit_posts' => true));
add_role('barber_shop',_('Barber Shop'),array('read' => true, 'edit_posts' => true));
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

My question is, do I need to call this code once, or should I always keep it running? Will it cause any issue in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would call this code in a [plugin activation hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/) or at the very least, [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/). The issue you *may* run into is calling this code too early if it's outside any specific WordPress hooks which would cause issues. That being said, [`add_role()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/) calls [`WP_Roles::add_role()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/add_role/) and one of the first things it does is check if it's already defined via:

```
if( empty( $role ) || isset( $this->roles[ $role ] ) ) {
    return;
}
```

WordPress saves roles in the options table and grabs those roles on instantiation. If the role is already set, it's just going to return early no harm, no foul.

Comment: I'm using it with Code Snippets plugin and the code is currently disabled. So since both roles are saved in the options table, there is no need to call this code, unless I reset the entire DB/WP Project - Correct?

Comment: Right now? Yes. The roles should be saved, and you can remove the code. **BUT** the future is unknown; if you want to "future-proof" your code, you'd want to move these `add_roles()` to a plugin. On the off-chance your roles somehow get reset sometime down the line; the plugin that adds the roles will ensure that these stay in place.